# How to Sort Product collection by Price?

Tags: magento2

I want to get the max price of all products using product collection.
I tried the below but it didn't work

```
$collection = $this->_productFactory->create()
            ->getCollection()
            ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
            ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
            ->getFirstItem();

        print_r($collection->getPrice());
```

How to get max price and min price of products from product collection in magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

Half answer already answered by @hitesh. you can get **min** and **max** price from product collection

```
$maxPrice = $collection->getMaxPrice();
$minPrice = $collection->getMinPrice();
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-get-min-price-max-price-product-collection/)

Comment: I didnt get...using $collection->getMaxPrice or getMinPrice()..

Comment: remove this line  `->getFirstItem();` it will load first product object.

Answer (score 1):

Use addAttributeToSort() function for sorting product collection by price.

```
$collection->setOrder('price', 'DESC');
```

Change to

```
$collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'DESC');
```

Comment: It didnt work...

Answer (score 1):

```
        $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $productCollection->setOrder('price', 'DESC');
        $minPrice=$productCollection->getMinPrice();
        $maxPrice=$productCollection->getMaxPrice();
```